# Adding OWL sameAs axiom in java

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

In Java OWL API, equivalent classes can be added using `OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom`. Is there any similar class for adding OWL SameAs axiom?

Comment: Joshua has already answered this question. Rule of thumb for any axiom is to search for classes whose name is OWL*keyword*Axiom - Eclipse has a quick type search that allows that. I believe other IDEs have a similar function.

Comment: @Ignazio I think 010101 actually might have tried that, but was confused about the name of the axiom (note "for adding OWL sameAs axiom"). I sometimes wish that the OWL RDF vocabulary had used sameIndividual to make it clear that it's the equivalence relation for individuals, not anything else.  Instead we end up with people using sameAs with classes, properties, etc., instead of equivalentClass,etc.

Comment: I believe in linked data sameAs is used for both. Creates a bit of confusion indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would want [OWLSameIndividualAxiom](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLSameIndividualAxiom.html). Even though the RDF serialization uses owl:sameAs, it's a SameIndividual axiom, not a SameAs axiom.

Comment: Is it possible to map two classes using `OWLSameIndividualAxiom`? Or is it just for `NamedIndividuals`?

Comment: Only same individuals. For classes, you can only use punning - creating individuals with the same IRIs as the classes you want to declare sameAs

Comment: @Ignazio, The answer was very helpful, what would be the methods to make two classes same?